# ESLint: 'React' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars) when using JSX pragma

Tags: reactjs, jsx, emotion, eslint-config-airbnb, airbnb-js-styleguide

How do I stop eslint throwing an error when I use the jsx pragma.

I'm using the airbnb config and I've tried adding `"react/jsx-uses-react": 1,` as a rule which hasn't worked.

Do I need to include `plugin:react/recommended` in the extends when using the airbnb?

```
.eslintrc.js

  extends: [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:react-redux/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier/react",
  ],
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: "detect",
    },
  },
  plugins: ["emotion", "graphql", "prettier", "react-redux"],
  rules: {
    "emotion/jsx-import": "error",
    "emotion/no-vanilla": "error",
    "emotion/import-from-emotion": "error",
    "emotion/styled-import": "error",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] }],
    "graphql/template-strings": [
      `error`,
      {
        env: `relay`,
        tagName: `graphql`,
      },
    ],
  },
```

```
layout.js

/* ESLint: 'React' is defined but never used.(no-unused-vars) */
import React from "react" 
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

/** @jsx jsx */
import { Global, css, jsx } from "@emotion/core"
import { ThemeProvider } from "emotion-theming"
```

Comment: check this: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9583

Comment: @Fryla-CristianMarucci Are you suggesting I need to add babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx?

Comment: Yes, I think it can worth the try.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem exporting only a styled component.  I wrapped it in `<React.Fragment>` and exported that instead.

Before:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

export const LabelText = styled.span`
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 500;
`;
```

After:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from '@emotion/styled';

const StyledSpan = styled.span`
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

export const LabelText = ({ children }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <StyledSpan>{children}</StyledSpan>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```